# AngularJS Protractor - Finding an Element on a Page Using Ng-Click Binding

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a button on a page that looks like:

```
<button ng-click="myFunction()" ng-show="flag">
    Submit
</button>
```

The element has no ID.

Is there a way to find this element using the function bound to Ng-Click?  Or do I have to assign an ID to this element to locate it using Jasmine / Protractor?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I went through the Protractor API and didn't find anything related to finding an element through `ng-click`.  I did find

`element(by.buttonText("Submit"));`

Not quite the same, but does the job in my environment.

Comment: Although this works, it's worth noting that this [isn't recommended by the protractor style guide](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide#http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide#prefer-by-id-and-by-css-when-no-protractor-locators-are-available). I think I would assign an ID to it so that it can be found easily.

Comment: It won't work if your button is a `div` or any non-button-type button.

Comment: @YuxuanChen Who said anything about a `<div>` or any other non `<button>` element?  I like your enthusiasm for StackOverflow though.  Keep up the hard work.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I had a list of dynamic buttons being generated from a DB and my case required clicking a button by specific text as the text in question was not unique. i.e. [Admin] button vs [Administrator]. Finding a button by 'Admin' was troublesome. thank you

Answer (score 71):

Just tested this and it works:

```
element(by.css('[ng-click="myFunction()"]'))
```

Comment: confirm this. escape quotes (\") might be necessary.

Comment: IMHO, I think Lloyd Banks anwser is better. __E2E tests are meant to test UI__. They should rely on __things visible to user__, like button label "Submit", not the logic hidden in HTML attributes.

Comment: @matewka I would disagree, making it rely on text in the UI will be very fragile... And weather the user sees Submit, SUBMIT should not matter, and a simple uppercase can then break all your tests in a single go... Not to mention localisation... Ofc. on the flipside we need to ensure ng-click="submit()" isn't bound to our Cancel button...

Comment: I find the click then test that it has the text I expect to be displayed to the user.  That way I fewer fragile UI-text based tests and get the back-end wiring validated.

Comment: If the function has parameters in the code, does my protractor test need to include those as well?

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that it works for elements that are not defined as an HTML <button>.  In my case, I'm working with an element that's a <span> which has a btn class.  Lloyd Banks is right about by.buttonText() in cases where you truly have a <button> element.

Comment: Hi, i have just tried it, but my test is passed and the click action isn't done ! Here my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225676/click-into-an-icon-isnt-working-on-protractor

Comment: who supports only one language? Never trust on UI text

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ng-show`, you could try this:

```
element(by.Css("button[ng-show]")); // Get element with tag < button > and has ng-show attribute
```

or:

```
element(by.Css("button[ng-show*=flag]")); // Get element with tag < button > and has ng-show attribute which contains word flag
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding an ID, which I don't like to do just to provide a test hook, I would add `type="submit"` to the button and then you can search `By.css('[type="submit"]')`