# protractor cannot locate element with css on ng-click element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, css-selectors, protractor

html:

```
<button class="helperButton ng-scope" ng-if="!isDisabled && displayHelper( 'none' )" ng-click="select( 'none', $event );" type="button">  ×  Select None</button>
```

trying to locate with:

```
element(by.css('button[ng-click="select( \'none\', $event );"]'));
```

get error:

> Failed: No element found using locator:
>   By.cssSelector("button[ng-click=\"select( 'none', $event );\"]")

this link provides a solution [AngularJS Protractor - Finding an Element on a Page Using Ng-Click Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807702/angularjs-protractor-finding-an-element-on-a-page-using-ng-click-binding) but does not have details to the function its referencing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Having your locator based on the `ng-click` is not quite reliable and readable.

Instead I would rely *on the button text*:

```
by.xpath('//button[contains(., "Select None")]')
```

or, on the *class*:

```
by.css('button.helperButton')
```

Or, if have a control over the application HTML templates - add an `id` attribute and use:

```
by.id('mybuttonid')
```

---

If you still want to use `ng-click` - try using `starts-with` CSS selector syntax to check `ng-click` attribute:

```
by.css('button[ng-click^=select]')
```

Comment: I tried button text but it has that strange x character and all those spaces that makes it not work.

Comment: @awaken well, that's why I've used `contains()`. It is strange that you still cannot locate it. Are there any `frame` or `iframe` elements on the page? Thanks.

Comment: the page has tons of elements that meet those locating methods and I will get `WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.xpath("//button[contains(., \"Select None\")]") - the first result will be used` thats why I'm using ng-click

Comment: @awaken well, if there are many elements with `Select None` text inside - I suspect `ng-click` would also be the same for them. How do you know which one do you need? Thanks.

Comment: xpath `//*[@id='-search-form']/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/button[2]` works but I try to stay away from xpaths because they can be brittle.

Comment: @awaken well, it depends on how you write it. The one you've presented looks very fragile and depends very much on the page structure. You need to identify key elements with unique attributes which you can rely on. Is there any chance to see the HTML code of the page? Thanks.

Comment: there are multiple angular elements that basically reuse the same plugin. Each of those have a Select None button and their ng-click has the same function. I guess I'm stuck with using xpath. Thanks for your help regardless.

Comment: @awaken okay, but how these angular elements differ - could you show an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72716/discussion-between-awaken-and-alecxe).

Comment: @awaken could you remember if we solved this problem back in march? Thanks.